# How can I create a chained certificate using self signed chains of certificate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, openssl, ca

I am trying to convert my rails application to work as https://. For testing purpose I created a self signed certificate using openssl. I am using nginx as web server. Then I configured the nginx using this certificate.

But while taking the application it shows https:// before the address but showing a result as 
**This webpage has a redirect loop, This webpage https://myapp.com has resulted too many redirects** in chrome and another browsers are also showing redirect issues.

After too many research I found a clue like need to use chained certificate to fix this problem. Then I tried to create chains of certificate. The way I used is explaining below.

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -out ca.csr -keyout ca.key
openssl x509 -trustout -signkey ca.key -days 365 -req -in ca.csr -out ca.pem
```

The I copied the ca.pem to

```
/etc/ssl/certs
```

and ca.key to

```
/etc/ssl/private
```

Then edited the **openssl.conf** as per needs and created two new directories **CA and newcerts** inside **/etc/ssl**.

and provide new serial and database file by running the following commands.

```
sudo sh -c "echo '01' > /etc/ssl/CA/serial"
sudo touch /etc/ssl/CA/index.txt
```

Then I created a client certificate by running the following commands.

```
openssl genrsa -out client.key 1024
openssl req -new -key client.key -out client.csr
openssl ca -in client.csr -out client.cer
```

This certificate is depends on **ca.pem**

Then I created a 3rd cerificate from the second cerificate means **client.cer** and that not depends on **ca.pem** using the following command.

```
 # Create a certificate request
 openssl req -new -keyout client1.key -out client1.request -days 365

 # Create and sign the certificate
 openssl ca -policy policy_anything -keyfile client.key -cert client.pem -out client1.pem -infiles client1.request
```

and changed the openssl.conf option

```
[ usr_cert ]
basicConstraints=CA:TRUE # prev value was FALSE
```

Now I have a certificate chain like

ca.pem -> client.pem -> client1.pem

How can I bundle these three certificates to create a chained certificate properly. I tried in my own way but it shows the same error.

Can anyone please help to solve the issue, Past one week am working on the problem.

Thanks 
Regards

Comment: As I understand it, you would like to have either a single ASN.1 blob that contains all three, or an ASN.1 blob that contains ca.pem and client.pem (I'd call it intermediary.pem to be clear!!!)

Answer (score 2):

Redirect loop has nothing to do with certificate chain or certificate format for that matter. You have an error in either web server configration or application logic. I am guessing you are trying to redirect to https from http, but redirect is also served from https, so this results in a loop.

Google Chrome (and other browsers to some extend) caches redirects, so it might be hard to properly debug and fix the issue with loops (it might still redirect even though you fix the issue on the server/app side). Make sure your requests are hitting the backend, clear browser caches or tools like curl to properly debug the issue.